# Joining tables and then referencing themselves

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables: a list of actors (actors.sql), a list of films (movies.sql), and a list of what actors played in each film (as well as their roles, roles.sql). Here is a snippet of each table: [image: sqlsnippet]

The tables are much, much longer, with thousands of entries not shown in this image. A prior practice question I had was to display a table of each film an actor had appeared in (actor name retrieved from HTML form and PHP on another page). The code for that was as follows:

```
    SELECT actor_id, movie_id, name, year
    FROM roles r
    JOIN actors a ON a.id = r.actor_id
    JOIN movies m ON m.id = r.movie_id
    WHERE first_name = '$actor_first' AND last_name = '$actor_last'
    ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Now I want to cross-reference the tables and find out who has worked with a specific actor and which films they have worked with. Say I want to see which films "Kevin Spacey" has appear in with "Will Smith", I would like a table that lists them. The problem is, I'm not sure how.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve it for a specific actor, say you have the actor_id and you want to find who worked with him and in what films?

Comment: That is exactly it. In the end, I would just like a list of films and the year of each film. The list of films should be which films actor A has been in with actor B (in my example, the films where Kevin Spacey has appeared with Will Smith).

Comment: Ok, you have both actors as a input or just one of both?

Comment: Both of them, but for the sake of example, a static actor would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both actors, you can do it with this query

```
select m.*
  from movies m
 where exists (select 1
                 from roles r1
                      inner join actors a1
                         on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id
                where r1.movie_id = m.movie_id
                  and a1.first_name = 'Kevin'
                  and a1.last_name = 'Spacey')
   and exists (select 1
                 from roles r2
                      inner join actors a2
                         on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id
                where r2.movie_id = m.movie_id
                  and a2.first_name = 'Will'
                  and a2.last_name = 'Smith')
```

it will return all movie data for all movies where both actors play a role.

Comment: what if you need to find more that 2 actors? do you have to supply another `exists`?

Comment: If you want the movies where 3 actors have a role together, yes, another exists

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the accepted answer, you can just do it like this, counting the number of records of the `movie_ID` in the result and which is equal to the number of actors you have supplied in the condition.

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    movies m
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.movie_ID
            FROM    roles a
                    INNER JOIN actors b
                        ON a.actor_ID = b.id
            WHERE   (b.first_name = 'Kevin' AND  b.last_name = 'Spacey') OR
                    (b.first_name = 'Will' AND  b.last_name = 'Smith')
            GROUP BY a.movie_ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        ) n ON m.movie_ID = n.movie_ID
```

*What is happening on the query?*

```
WHERE   (b.first_name = 'Kevin' AND  b.last_name = 'Spacey') OR
        (b.first_name = 'Will' AND  b.last_name = 'Smith')
```

this is where you will find as many actors as you want by adding `OR` conditional operator

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

the value of `COUNT` should be equal to the number of actors you want to search.

of if you need to find 3 actors that worked together on the same film, so you should only modify the `WHERE` clause and and the value of the `HAVING` clause.

```
WHERE   (b.first_name = 'Kevin' AND  b.last_name = 'Spacey') OR
        (b.first_name = 'Will' AND  b.last_name = 'Smith') OR
        (b.first_name = 'Ben' AND  b.last_name = 'Affleck')
GROUP BY a.movie_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you, both explanations greatly enhance my understanding of SQL as a programming language. Just curious: what formatting should I follow when writing SQL queries? I tend to use the K&R style, but I'm not sure what to indent.

Comment: By formatting I mean indenting, etc. It's kind of hard to explain K&R in such a small comment box, but it seems like you follow the Allman formatting style, whereas jachguate follows the Pico style.